# mysql cell in textbox

Tags: php, textbox

I want to have a cell in my mysql database as the value in a textbox.

I want to have the FirstName column for person with CustomerID of say, 1 in the textbox.

This is my coding.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","cmcclintock","000547") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("fleet hire motors") or die(mysql_error());
$CustomerID = $_GET["customerid"]; 
$query=mysql_query("SELECT FirstName FROM customer WHERE CustomerID = $CustomerID") or     die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);


echo ($CustomerID);
echo ($query);
echo ($row);


?> 
<form name="custedit2" method=GET action="editcustomersubmit.php">
First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="<?php echo ($query); ?>">
<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Save">
<input name="resubmitbtn" type="submit" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this shows enough to explain what I am looking for.

Comment: you dont have to put braces around string/variable while echoing it,echo ($CustomerID); would be only echo $CustomerID;  value="<?php echo ($row['FirstName']); ?>"

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="FirstName" type="text" value="<?php echo ($row['FirstName']); ?>">
```

$row is where your result set is stored, so you use this to display the column that you want